# Reading the same set of records in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, mybatis

My Batch job 'MyBatisPagingItemReader' is reading the same set of records. Below is the config.

```
<job id="synchBatchJob">
    <step id="simpleStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="synchItemReader" processor="synchBatchProcessor" writer="synchItemWriter"
                   **commit-interval="10"**>
              <listeners>
        <listener ref="synchBatchStepListener" />
        </listeners>
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="synchItemReader"
         class="org.mybatis.spring.batch.MyBatisPagingItemReader" scope="step" >
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
        <property name="parameterValues" ref="syncJobParams" />
        <property name="queryId" value="getStagingData" />
        <property **name="pageSize" value="10"** />
    </bean>
<util:map id="syncJobParams" scope="step">
        <entry key="activityId" 
               value="#{jobParameters['activity.id']}"/>
    </util:map>
```

I have mentioned "commit-interval" in step definition & "pageSize" in MyBatisPagingItemReader as "10". I have total of 12 records in table. My reader always gives me first 10 set of records.
But if i mention "pageSize" = 100, Iam getting two call to writer with 10 and 2 in each set while writing which is correct.

Can anyone point me where iam going wrong?

Comment: Let us see your query, problem with your query.

Comment: Below is Mybatis Query which is pretty simple

<select id="getStagingData" resultType="hashmap" >
       SELECT
                *
       FROM
                ACTIVITY_DATA
       WHERE
                ACTIVITY_ID = #{activityId}
    </select>

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incomplete though in your configuration you have mentioned pagesize to 10 but you have not modified your query to support your configuration.

```
<select id="getStagingData" resultType="hashmap" > 
    select * from (
    select * from (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ACTIVITY_DATA 
    WHERE ACTIVITY_ID = #{activityId}
    order by activityId
   )) where ROWNUM_ <![CDATA[ > ]]> ( #_page# * #_pagesize# )
) where ROWNUM <![CDATA[ <= ]]> #_pagesize#

</select>
```

**Note:** This configuration is specific to oracle you need to modify ROWNUM according to your database implementation.